# change to dynamic vba

Tags: excel, vba

i want to have rows from one worsheet copy to another worksheet based on a specific text, i need it to run as new data will be added daily, i am using this code now but it needs to be run after inputting data.

```
 Sub CopyYes()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MAINGANG")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("REPAIRS")

    j = 4     
    For Each c In Source.Range("C4:C10000")   
        If c = "X" Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
           j = j + 1
    End If
Next c    
End Sub
```

Comment: Option Explicit
Sub CopyCCellVals()
  Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht6 As Worksheet
  Dim i As Integer, lastRow As Integer, sht6Row As Integer

  sht6Row = 5
  Set sht1 = Worksheets("MAINGANG")
  Set sht6 = Worksheets("REPAIRS")
  With sht1
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To lastRow
      If .Cells(i, "C") = "X" Or .Cells(i, "C") = "x" Then
         sht6.Cells(sht6Row, "A") = .Cells(i, "A")
         sht6Row = sht6Row + 1
      End If
    Next
  End With
End Sub


  How can I get this code to gather the data from worksheets 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will achieve what you are looking for:

```
 Sub CopyYes()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim LastColumnSource As Long 'Integer data type is outdated.
    Dim LastRowTarget As Long
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim TargetRange As Range
    Dim myArray As Variant

    Set SourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") <~~ change to your sheet name
    Set TargetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") <~~ change to your sheet name

    'Change the 1 to whichever column you need (1 represents column A)
    LastRowTarget = TargetSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowSource = SourceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    Set SourceRange = SourceSheet.Range("C4:C" & LastRowSource)

    j = 4
    For Each myCell In SourceRange
        If myCell.Value = "X" Then
           LastColumnSource = SourceSheet.Cells(myCell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
           myArray = SourceSheet.Range(Cells(myCell.Row, 1), Cells(myCell.Row, LastColumnSource))

           LastColumnTarget = TargetSheet.Cells(LastRowTarget, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
           Set TargetRange = TargetSheet.Range("A" & LastRowTarget)
           TargetRange.Resize(1, UBound(myArray, 2)) = myArray


           LastRowTarget = LastRowTarget + 1

        End If
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

To make it dynamic, the last row and last column are found for both sheets and the row is written to an array to then write back to the results sheet (which avoids the use of copy).

As I don't know enough about your project, I've left the `ActiveWorkbook` in but you'd be better to specify the workbook (or ThisWorkbook if it's the workbook the code is run from) - This avoids runtime errors if the code executes whilst another workbook is in focus.

Comment: how do you have this run constant in the background without having to always press the run code in VBA window?

Comment: Well that depends on a few things. When should this code run? What should trigger it?

Comment: @TimHackney, you can run the code in various ways, you could assign it to a button on your worksheet for example (put a shape/form control button on your sheet and right click > assign macro) or you could run the code from a `Worksheet` event such as when a calculation occurs or a cell is changed. [This MS Office support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/run-a-macro-5e855fd2-02d1-45f5-90a3-50e645fe3155) should steer you in the right direction to working it out.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I use an array to process, as follows
’--------------------------------

```
dim arr(),temp()
worksheets(1).activate
arr=[a1].currentregion

j=0
for i=1 to ubound(arr)
 if arr(i)="x" then
  j=j+1
  redim preserve temp(j)
  temp(j)=arr(i)
 end if
next

worksheets(2).activate
range("a1:a"&ubound(temp))=temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 Sub CopyYes()
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, r As Long
    Dim j As Integer, c As Integer

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MAINGANG")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("REPAIRS")

    vDB = Source.UsedRange

    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)
    For i = 4 To r
        If vDB(i, 3) = "X" Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To c, 1 To n)
            For j = 1 To c
                vR(j, n) = vDB(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    End If
    Target.Range("a4").Resize(n, c) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```